# Adding a sound effect to a jump

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

I want to add a sound effect to a jump action when my character jumps. It sounds simple to do but i just cannot do it, this is what I've tried so far..

In my header file for my character I have:

```
SystemSoundID jump;
- (void)playSound:(NSString *)jump1 :(NSString *) mp3;
```

In my implementation file I have:

```
- (void)playSound :(NSString *)jump1 :(NSString *) mp3{

    SystemSoundID audioEffect;

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource : jump1 ofType :mp3];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath : path]) {

        NSURL *pathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path];

        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef) pathURL, &audioEffect);

        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(audioEffect);
    }

    else {

        NSLog(@"error , file not found aye: %@", path);
    }
}
```

Also inside the function jump I have:

```
[self playSound:@"jump" :@"mp3"];
```

Please excuse my inexperience I just had a go at it as it would be a great feature for my game, if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong or a different and better way to do it that works that would be great thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this method in a class and whenever you want to play the sound just call this method using [self playSound], jump.mp3 should be in your bundle, and remember one thing more don't forget to add AudioToolbox framework.

```
-(void) playSound {
NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"jump" ofType:@"mp3"];
SystemSoundID soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath: soundPath], &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);   
}
```